# Migrate from internal database to MSSQL

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am testing WSO2 API Manager locally and using the in-built database. I want to change the database form the internal database to MSSQL. Is there a way I can do this easily? Any tools/ scripts?

Trying to migrate from internal database to MSSQL

Answer (score 2):

WSO2 doesn't provide any tools to do Cross Database data migrations. But there are third-party tools that can do Data migration between H2 and MSSQL, but attempting a direct Data migration may be tricky, you may have to perform the migration and test the deployment thoroughly.

The most straightforward option is to create a new deployment with MSSQL and use [API Controller](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/api-controller/getting-started-with-wso2-api-controller/) to Migrate the APIs and Applications from the old environment to the new one.